# clojure/lein: Can I specify a project file for lein other than project.clj?

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen, ring

I have a couple of distinct jars I want to generate out of a single project.  I figure I can make a project.clj file for each one, but I can't name them all project.clj.  How do I tell lein to use another project file besides project.clj?  Or is there another way to generate jars or start

```
> lein ring server
```

for example, for many different project files in the same directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider restructing your project so that there is a sub-project for each jar. There is a plugin called [lein-sub](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-sub) that helps you to do that. For example, here is how [ring is structured](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring):

```
/ring-core/project.clj
/ring-devel/project.clj
/ring-jetty-adapter/project.clj
/ring-servlet/project.clj
/project.clj
```

Then in the "parent" project.clj, you can specifiy the sub-projects like so:

```
(defproject example "0.1.0"
  :sub
    ["ring-core"
     "ring-devel"
     "ring-jetty-adapter"
     "ring-servlet"])
```

Then you can run `lein sub jar` to generate jars for all your sub-projects. You can always just go into the sub-project directory and work on it as you would a normal lein project, too.